# Error trying to install shopify app in test store

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, shopify

I'm following the [rails 3 guide](http://wiki.shopify.com/Creating_an_app_and_deploying_it_to_Heroku_using_Rails_3) to create a shopify app using oauth2 to authenticate, but once I try to install the app in a test shop I get this error.

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The redirect_uri and application url must have matching hosts"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that the application URL you set in your app settings and the redirect URL you passed in your OAuth request are for different domains. Go check your app settings as well as the Omniauth setup file and make sure they're set up correctly.